# iReport - output does not match preview

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, text-formatting

I'm using `Jasper Report` and `iReport 5.5.1`. I created a grid using rectangles and inserted static text fields. My problem is that the PDF output created with Java is different from the iReport preview. Below you can see the three screenshots, first from the editor, the second is the preview and the third is the pdf output. We can see the overlap of the text and furthermore the bold title is not printed bold.

[image: HERE]

Comment: Cf. [JasperReports - Fonts Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html); it describes two samples, **Fonts** on *How to format texts using fonts properties* and **Font Extensions** on *How to ship the required fonts with your report templates when deploying them in the target application, using font extensions.* Both include PDF specific information.

Comment: I forgot to add jasperreports-fonts-xxx.jar....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a font issue.

To achieve the common behavior across all the outputs, Open the Ireport designer and apply below properties:

1. Font Name =  "Arial Unicode MS".
2. PDF font name = This property is deprecated, so leave it blank.
3. PDF Encoding = 'Identity-H (Unicode with horizontal writing)'.

Hope this help you.

Regards,
Srikanth Kattam

Comment: I can't leave PDF Font name blank, but only default... and i get an exception:   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not load the following font : 
pdfFontName   : Helvetica
pdfEncoding   : Identity-H
isPdfEmbedded : false

Comment: I solved the problem of the font, but i don't understand why the text overlaps with itself...